# Where did GADM get its data from?

Tags: svg, gis, geojson, shapefile

I need the administrative boundary data levels 0-4 (or as small as possible) for all countries of the world. The best source I can see so far - the most complete - is from GADM. However their license says not for commercial use, which I will intend to use it for.

I need the data in shapefile or geojson format in which I will convert to svg.

How did GADM get the data for all the administrative boundaries? I would be willing to spend time recreating all the data from scratch if I knew how or where to get data from.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you acquainted with https://d-maps.com/? 232547 maps, each one proposed in 6 graphic formats (GIF, PDF, CDR, **SVG**, AI, WMF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from GADM Wikipedia entry:

> GADM project created the spatial data for many countries from spatial databases provided by national governments, NGO, and/or from maps and lists of names available on the Internet (e.g. from Wikipedia).

Alternatives:

- Available by Country and Subject:

http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

- Download Free Shapefile Maps – Country Boundary Polygon, Rail-Road, Water polyline etc:

https://www.igismap.com/download-free-shapefile-maps/amp/

- Admin 0 - Countries

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/50m-admin-0-countries-2/

- World Borders Dataset

http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

- By Country

https://geonode.wfp.org/wfpdocs/?limit=10&offset=0

`- CAR - Administrative boundaries (Shapefile 4 levels)` < -- This

https://data.world/iom/853bc4cc-55bb-4d00-8c63-a28fc1f130f5

- OpenStreetMap Data Extracts

http://download.geofabrik.de